# Fill in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Can't seem to find the answer to this question, but maybe because it's too simple. I'm trying to use an autocomplete based on Jquery UI and I'm using their remoteJson datasource where you type in something and it pulls a list of data from a source. However, when you click on the autocomplete, it doesn't fill the data to your textbox even though they store the callback. Was wondering how to configure it so that after you click the autocomplete, it automatically completes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

You can selected value in `"ui.item"`

[refer to this link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

If you want fill the same text box with selected value you can use

```
$(this).value =  ui.item.label
```

inside select function

Comment: I'm using this link http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp THe issue happens after I click the autocomplete and it doesn't fill in the rest of the thing